# White screen when I perform grapicstest in ili9341

Tags: arduino-uno

I get a white screen when I perform grapicstest in ili9341. I used the below code:

```
#include "SPI.h"
#include "Adafruit_GFX.h"
#include "Adafruit_ILI9341.h"

// For the Adafruit shield, these are the default.
#define TFT_DC 9
#define TFT_CS 10

// Use hardware SPI (on Uno, #13, #12, #11) and the above for CS/DC
Adafruit_ILI9341 tft = Adafruit_ILI9341(TFT_CS, TFT_DC);
// If using the breakout, change pins as desired
//Adafruit_ILI9341 tft = Adafruit_ILI9341(TFT_CS, TFT_DC, TFT_MOSI, TFT_CLK, TFT_RST, TFT_MISO);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("ILI9341 Test!"); 

  tft.begin();

  // read diagnostics (optional but can help debug problems)
  uint8_t x = tft.readcommand8(ILI9341_RDMODE);
  Serial.print("Display Power Mode: 0x"); Serial.println(x, HEX);
  x = tft.readcommand8(ILI9341_RDMADCTL);
  Serial.print("MADCTL Mode: 0x"); Serial.println(x, HEX);
  x = tft.readcommand8(ILI9341_RDPIXFMT);
  Serial.print("Pixel Format: 0x"); Serial.println(x, HEX);
  x = tft.readcommand8(ILI9341_RDIMGFMT);
  Serial.print("Image Format: 0x"); Serial.println(x, HEX);
  x = tft.readcommand8(ILI9341_RDSELFDIAG);
  Serial.print("Self Diagnostic: 0x"); Serial.println(x, HEX); 

  Serial.println(F("Benchmark                Time (microseconds)"));
  delay(10);
  Serial.print(F("Screen fill              "));
  Serial.println(testFillScreen());
  delay(500);

  Serial.print(F("Text                     "));
  Serial.println(testText());
  delay(3000);

  Serial.print(F("Lines                    "));
  Serial.println(testLines(ILI9341_CYAN));
  delay(500);

  Serial.print(F("Horiz/Vert Lines         "));
  Serial.println(testFastLines(ILI9341_RED, ILI9341_BLUE));
  delay(500);

  Serial.print(F("Rectangles (outline)     "));
  Serial.println(testRects(ILI9341_GREEN));
  delay(500);

  Serial.print(F("Rectangles (filled)      "));
  Serial.println(testFilledRects(ILI9341_YELLOW, ILI9341_MAGENTA));
  delay(500);

  Serial.print(F("Circles (filled)         "));
  Serial.println(testFilledCircles(10, ILI9341_MAGENTA));

  Serial.print(F("Circles (outline)        "));
  Serial.println(testCircles(10, ILI9341_WHITE));
  delay(500);

  Serial.print(F("Triangles (outline)      "));
  Serial.println(testTriangles());
  delay(500);

  Serial.print(F("Triangles (filled)       "));
  Serial.println(testFilledTriangles());
  delay(500);

  Serial.print(F("Rounded rects (outline)  "));
  Serial.println(testRoundRects());
  delay(500);

  Serial.print(F("Rounded rects (filled)   "));
  Serial.println(testFilledRoundRects());
  delay(500);

  Serial.println(F("Done!"));

}


void loop(void) {
  for(uint8_t rotation=0; rotation<4; rotation++) {
    tft.setRotation(rotation);
    testText();
    delay(1000);
  }
}

unsigned long testFillScreen() {
  unsigned long start = micros();
  tft.fillScreen(ILI9341_BLACK);
  yield();
  tft.fillScreen(ILI9341_RED);
  yield();
  tft.fillScreen(ILI9341_GREEN);
  yield();
  tft.fillScreen(ILI9341_BLUE);
  yield();
  tft.fillScreen(ILI9341_BLACK);
  yield();
  return micros() - start;
}

unsigned long testText() {
  tft.fillScreen(ILI9341_BLACK);
  unsigned long start = micros();
  tft.setCursor(0, 0);
  tft.setTextColor(ILI9341_WHITE);  tft.setTextSize(1);
  tft.println("Hello World!");
  tft.setTextColor(ILI9341_YELLOW); tft.setTextSize(2);
  tft.println(1234.56);
  tft.setTextColor(ILI9341_RED);    tft.setTextSize(3);
  tft.println(0xDEADBEEF, HEX);
  tft.println();
  tft.setTextColor(ILI9341_GREEN);
  tft.setTextSize(5);
  tft.println("Groop");
  tft.setTextSize(2);
  tft.println("I implore thee,");
  tft.setTextSize(1);
  tft.println("my foonting turlingdromes.");
  tft.println("And hooptiously drangle me");
  tft.println("with crinkly bindlewurdles,");
  tft.println("Or I will rend thee");
  tft.println("in the gobberwarts");
  tft.println("with my blurglecruncheon,");
  tft.println("see if I don't!");
  return micros() - start;
}

unsigned long testLines(uint16_t color) {
  unsigned long start, t;
  int           x1, y1, x2, y2,
                w = tft.width(),
                h = tft.height();

  tft.fillScreen(ILI9341_BLACK);
  yield();

  x1 = y1 = 0;
  y2    = h - 1;
  start = micros();
  for(x2=0; x2<w; x2+=6) tft.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, color);
  x2    = w - 1;
  for(y2=0; y2<h; y2+=6) tft.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, color);
  t     = micros() - start; // fillScreen doesn't count against timing

  yield();
  tft.fillScreen(ILI9341_BLACK);
  yield();

  x1    = w - 1;
  y1    = 0;
  y2    = h - 1;
  start = micros();
  for(x2=0; x2<w; x2+=6) tft.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, color);
  x2    = 0;
  for(y2=0; y2<h; y2+=6) tft.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, color);
  t    += micros() - start;

  yield();
  tft.fillScreen(ILI9341_BLACK);
  yield();

  x1    = 0;
  y1    = h - 1;
  y2    = 0;
  start = micros();
  for(x2=0; x2<w; x2+=6) tft.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, color);
  x2    = w - 1;
  for(y2=0; y2<h; y2+=6) tft.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, color);
  t    += micros() - start;

  yield();
  tft.fillScreen(ILI9341_BLACK);
  yield();

  x1    = w - 1;
  y1    = h - 1;
  y2    = 0;
  start = micros();
  for(x2=0; x2<w; x2+=6) tft.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, color);
  x2    = 0;
  for(y2=0; y2<h; y2+=6) tft.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, color);

  yield();
  return micros() - start;
}

unsigned long testFastLines(uint16_t color1, uint16_t color2) {
  unsigned long start;
  int           x, y, w = tft.width(), h = tft.height();

  tft.fillScreen(ILI9341_BLACK);
  start = micros();
  for(y=0; y<h; y+=5) tft.drawFastHLine(0, y, w, color1);
  for(x=0; x<w; x+=5) tft.drawFastVLine(x, 0, h, color2);

  return micros() - start;
}

unsigned long testRects(uint16_t color) {
  unsigned long start;
  int           n, i, i2,
                cx = tft.width()  / 2,
                cy = tft.height() / 2;

  tft.fillScreen(ILI9341_BLACK);
  n     = min(tft.width(), tft.height());
  start = micros();
  for(i=2; i<n; i+=6) {
    i2 = i / 2;
    tft.drawRect(cx-i2, cy-i2, i, i, color);
  }

  return micros() - start;
}

unsigned long testFilledRects(uint16_t color1, uint16_t color2) {
  unsigned long start, t = 0;
  int           n, i, i2,
                cx = tft.width()  / 2 - 1,
                cy = tft.height() / 2 - 1;

  tft.fillScreen(ILI9341_BLACK);
  n = min(tft.width(), tft.height());
  for(i=n; i>0; i-=6) {
    i2    = i / 2;
    start = micros();
    tft.fillRect(cx-i2, cy-i2, i, i, color1);
    t    += micros() - start;
    // Outlines are not included in timing results
    tft.drawRect(cx-i2, cy-i2, i, i, color2);
    yield();
  }

  return t;
}

unsigned long testFilledCircles(uint8_t radius, uint16_t color) {
  unsigned long start;
  int x, y, w = tft.width(), h = tft.height(), r2 = radius * 2;

  tft.fillScreen(ILI9341_BLACK);
  start = micros();
  for(x=radius; x<w; x+=r2) {
    for(y=radius; y<h; y+=r2) {
      tft.fillCircle(x, y, radius, color);
    }
  }

  return micros() - start;
}

unsigned long testCircles(uint8_t radius, uint16_t color) {
  unsigned long start;
  int           x, y, r2 = radius * 2,
                w = tft.width()  + radius,
                h = tft.height() + radius;

  // Screen is not cleared for this one -- this is
  // intentional and does not affect the reported time.
  start = micros();
  for(x=0; x<w; x+=r2) {
    for(y=0; y<h; y+=r2) {
      tft.drawCircle(x, y, radius, color);
    }
  }

  return micros() - start;
}

unsigned long testTriangles() {
  unsigned long start;
  int           n, i, cx = tft.width()  / 2 - 1,
                      cy = tft.height() / 2 - 1;

  tft.fillScreen(ILI9341_BLACK);
  n     = min(cx, cy);
  start = micros();
  for(i=0; i<n; i+=5) {
    tft.drawTriangle(
      cx    , cy - i, // peak
      cx - i, cy + i, // bottom left
      cx + i, cy + i, // bottom right
      tft.color565(i, i, i));
  }

  return micros() - start;
}

unsigned long testFilledTriangles() {
  unsigned long start, t = 0;
  int           i, cx = tft.width()  / 2 - 1,
                   cy = tft.height() / 2 - 1;

  tft.fillScreen(ILI9341_BLACK);
  start = micros();
  for(i=min(cx,cy); i>10; i-=5) {
    start = micros();
    tft.fillTriangle(cx, cy - i, cx - i, cy + i, cx + i, cy + i,
      tft.color565(0, i*10, i*10));
    t += micros() - start;
    tft.drawTriangle(cx, cy - i, cx - i, cy + i, cx + i, cy + i,
      tft.color565(i*10, i*10, 0));
    yield();
  }

  return t;
}

unsigned long testRoundRects() {
  unsigned long start;
  int           w, i, i2,
                cx = tft.width()  / 2 - 1,
                cy = tft.height() / 2 - 1;

  tft.fillScreen(ILI9341_BLACK);
  w     = min(tft.width(), tft.height());
  start = micros();
  for(i=0; i<w; i+=6) {
    i2 = i / 2;
    tft.drawRoundRect(cx-i2, cy-i2, i, i, i/8, tft.color565(i, 0, 0));
  }

  return micros() - start;
}

unsigned long testFilledRoundRects() {
  unsigned long start;
  int           i, i2,
                cx = tft.width()  / 2 - 1,
                cy = tft.height() / 2 - 1;

  tft.fillScreen(ILI9341_BLACK);
  start = micros();
  for(i=min(tft.width(), tft.height()); i>20; i-=6) {
    i2 = i / 2;
    tft.fillRoundRect(cx-i2, cy-i2, i, i, i/8, tft.color565(0, i, 0));
    yield();
  }

  return micros() - start;
}
```

Comment: Please pare down your code to the absolute minimum. There is lots of code in there that is obviously superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have wired everything correctly? In particular:

- In most cases I have seen, the source of the problem was incorrect wiring of MOSI and SCLK. Do not trust the default constructor, better use the constructor that specifies the values of those pins.
- Check that the reset pin on your 9341 board is wired correctly.
- Power the 9341 with 5V; if you feed it 3.3V, the voltage regulator will not be able to supply a high enough voltage for the controller to work correctly.

You also haven't mentioned what you are running this on!

Comment: yes m using 5V only and my wiring is proper also i changed the position in breadboard so many times to make sure if the problem is coming from breadboard but still nothing happened please help